# Is it possible to `DELETE` in a subquery?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

Is it possible to run a `DELETE` as a subquery of a `SELECT`? Eg:

```
SELECT * FROM posts where title = (DELETE FROM posts returning 'whoops');
```

When I try this, I get `syntax error at or near "FROM"`, pointing to the `FROM` of the `DELETE`, so it doesn't seem possible, but maybe I'm just doing it wrong somehow.

Context: I'm trying to understand the possible damage of some SQL injection attacks. In this case, the overall query will be run in a prepared statement with no variable bindings. This means an attacker can't run multiple top-level statements, but I'm trying to assess the possible damage from subqueries.

Edit: I should have said, the querying code is doing something like:

```
 query_parameter = blindly_read_from_user_input()

 # this is just interpolated into a string
 db_query = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE title = '#{query_parameter}'"

 connection.prepare("query_name", db_query)
 connection.exec_prepared("query_name")
```

So:

- It's using a prepared statement, which means an attacker can't cause multiple top-level queries to run
- It's not using bound parameters

I'm trying to see whether I can delete records based on SQL injection in this existing query structure.

Comment: Have a look: http://blog.endpoint.com/2012/06/detecting-postgres-sql-injection.html

Comment: Do you want to delete all posts that the title is `'whoops'`?

Comment: This probably wouldn't be valid, unless there happened to only be one row in posts - this subquery would be expecting a single row and column. You could try wrapping the `DELETE` subquery in another subquery to ensure that only one value would be returned. That said, you might need to assign a column name to 'whoops' if this type of attack would work.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ - No, I believe the idea is the person doing the SQL injection attack would be trying to delete all posts, period - what's returned isn't important in and of itself.

Answer (score 9):

You can `DELETE` in a CTE - which is a different kind of subquery.

But you probably don't need it for this simple case, you just need to use `RETURNING` and fix the syntax errors in your code:

```
DELETE 
FROM posts AS p
WHERE p.title = 'whoops'
RETURNING p.* ;
```